# javascript coderbyte CoinDeterminer

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm completely stumped on this problem. Basically, given Number, return the fewest number of coins needed to add up to number given:

`coinsOriginal = [1,5,7,9,11]`

**If the coins used had to be unique**, I would just try something like recursively, total the array, slice it down by 1 element until zero length, then recursively try again with a shuffled array...

```
 count = 0;
'function recurse (coinsArr) {
    if (coinsArr.reduce(total) == goalNumber)
       return coinsArr.length; // ie return true

    else {

       if (coinsArr.length == 0){
          newArr = coinsArr.slice(1);
          return recurse(newArr);

       } else if (count == 1000){
         return false

       } else {
         newArr = yatesfischershuffle(coinsOriginal);
         count++;
         return recurse(newArr);
       }

    }
}
```

However, the problem actually states that numbers can be used more than once. This has me thinking loops within loops within loops. I thought about trying to recursively add more and more loops as needed. I thought about trying just a set number of loops. However, what if the number is like 250, would need 9 loops???

Is some sort of memoization table / object needed? Any tips?

*Using the JavaScript language, have the function CoinDeterminer(num) take the input, which will be an integer ranging from 1 to 250, and return an integer output that will specify the least number of coins, that when added, equal the input integer. Coins are based on a system as follows: there are coins representing the integers 1, 5, 7, 9, and 11. So for example: if num is 16, then the output should be 2 because you can achieve the number 16 with the coins 9 and 7. If num is 25, then the output should be 3 because you can achieve 25 with either 11, 9, and 5 coins or with 9, 9, and 7 coins.*